Interpretation of differently estimated Polygenic Risk Scores (PRSs) by PLINK2 --score command and population stratification based on these estimates
I would like to point two (out of many) options where PRSs can be estimated using PLINK2 --score command.
Given the Genome Wide Association Studies (GWAS) summary statistics file (generated by PLINK2) is trd.sum and the name given to target binary files in PLINK format (.fam, .bim and .bed) is tmp10k_buu_2 I can estimate PRSs using the following commands.

./plink2 --bfile tmp10k_buu_2 --score trd.sum 3 4 9 header --out trd making use of REF (reference allele)

./plink2 --bfile tmp10k_buu_2 --score trd.sum 3 6 9 header --out trd making use of A1 (alternative allele)


I observe that the PRSs generated by these two options are perfectly negatively correlated, and that is due to the allele used. However, I find a collection of negatives and positives as PRSs of target individuals from (say option 1) and the opposite sign with same magnitude with the other option (say option 2) above.
How to correctly interprete the risk when option 1 and 2 are used separately (say for instance, individual A's PRS estimated from option 1 (PRS_1_A) = -0.552 and individual B's PRS estimated from option 1 (PRS_1_B) = +0.036 and when computed the same using option 2 will give PRS_2_A = +0.552 and PRS_2_B = -0.036. Which individual is at higher risk)? This involves correct population stratification because the target individuals need to be sorted according to the PRS (say low to high risk), then using 2 different options cannot determine the person having lowest risk as per one option gets the highest risk by using the other.
Please clarify correct interpretation of PRSs estimated using the above two options.
